# Search Criteria not working with Soap API

Tags: magento2, soap, soap-api-v2

**Description:**

I am working with Soap API on Magento 2, I am trying to get a filtered list of all products on my store using the following code.

P.S: I have tried to filter other fields like Sku,Id and Name

**Problem:**

No matter how I change the search criteria array, It keeps returning the complete list of  unfiltered products.

Any Idea on what I am doing wrong?

```
        $wsdlurl = 'http://example.com/index.php/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1';

        $token = 'livutybnnlu6b6bhuvtr86f93p5khgjb';


        $opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer ".$token]];
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);

        $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlurl);
        $soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
        $soapClient->setStreamContext($context);

        $serviceArgs = array('searchCriteria'=> 
                                    array('filterGroups' => 
                                        array('filters' =>
                                            array('field' => 'typeId',
                                                   'value' => 'downloadable',

                                                   )
                                                 )
                                               )
                                             );


        $result = $soapClient->catalogProductRepositoryV1GetList($serviceArgs ); 
        echo var_dump( $result->result->items);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write the **SOAP** API, like below.

```
<?php

require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');

$token = 'seguq0wb13s495lip1j3p8ms3iledcnd'; // Use your Access Token
$wsdlUrl = 'http://YourMagentoRoot/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1';
$opts = ['http'=> ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " .$token]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$soapClient  = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);

// get all products or use filters on collection
$searchCriteria = [
    'searchCriteria' => [
        'filterGroups' => [
            [
                'filters' => [
                    [
                        'field' => 'sku',
                        'value' => '24-MB01',
                        'condition_type' => 'eq',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],

    ],
];

$soapClient  = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
$response = $soapClient->catalogProductRepositoryV1GetList($searchCriteria);
var_dump( $response->result->items);   ?>
```

Make sure to use your own access token and update the filter condition as per your requirement. Clear the cache and check the result. This is tested successfully in my local machine.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
Actually, The condition type is optional, it has  a default value = 'eq' 
(Check vendor/magento/framework/api/filter.php line75 )

Comment: ok, so even if adding the condition_type, you are getting the same result ?

Comment: Then , it could be due to the format of the search criteria. Try the updated syntax in my answer.

Comment: Didn't work either..

Comment: I have updated my answer and I made sure it works :) Please have a try

Comment: You are welcome :)